# KakaoTalk API - Bot

Tags: chatbot

I've created an app on https://developers.kakao.com/.
I'd like to use this app as a bot as it can be done with Line, or Messenger for example; by setting an endpoint URL pointing to a server of my own and collecting messages, send messages, ...
I don't see anywhere what's the id of my App, how to generate a QR code, so I could add it as a friend.

Could anyone tell me how the Kakaotalk app is working?

Thanks

Comment: Here is someone’s example project using node https://github.com/cheese10yun/KaKaoBot-Node/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you for this. I was more looking for information on how to configure the url of the bot server, and how to create a "brand" account.
I've finally discovered that I had to create a Plus Friend account and configure my bot server in the console provided.
It's not easy to find information as nothing is written in English. Fortunately Google is there to translate!

Comment: @Alexandre Can you please let me know how the Plus Friend account can be created or its url.
I am also trying to build a kakao bot, where a user communicate to a kakao bot and the bot should reply back to the user. Is there any way to receive the message sent by the user to a bot/app, by setting a webhook url.
I can see the API to sent message to user, I would also need to receive the messages sent by the user in a specifed url. Is there any way to set the callback/webhook url for an app/bot

Comment: @JijoJohn Did you get the answer to above?

Comment: Did anyone manage to solve this?