# Is there Kakao Talk Messaging API which is equivalent to LINE's Messaging API?

Tags: rest, messaging, chatbot

Is there Kakao Talk Messaging API which is equivalent to LINE's Messaging API?

LINE has "Messaging API" which allows 3rd party application to do following.

1. Auto-reply to message from LINE user
2. Push message to LINE user in an arbitrary timing

etc.

https://developers.line.me/en/services/messaging-api/

I'd like to do same thing with Kakao Talk, but I haven't been able to find **2 API to push message to Kakao Talk user in an arbitrary timing**.

I studied Kakao Talk APIs in the Kakao Talk developer site, but I couldn't find the equivalent APIs...

https://developers.kakao.com/features/platform

Also, I found the stackoverflow question [KakaoTalk API - Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282097/kakaotalk-api-bot), which suggests that I can do this in the Plus Friends account.

So I created an app in the Plus Friend account from the link below. The page is in Korean only, so I tried to understand the contents with Google Translate...

https://center-pf.kakao.com/

I found an Smart Chat API to **receive and auto-reply message** between Plus Friend account and Kakao Talk user.

However, this API **does not support push message** feature...

Could someone please advise where I can find the API to push message to Kakao Talk user from 3rd party app?

Answer (score 1):

I found that Kakao Talk does not disclose API for push message to Kakao Talk user to public. It is only available through their channel partner. So, I will close this question.